# Panel mount DC barrel jack on PCB

Tags: pcb, dc, connector

Is it possible to solder the panel mounted DC connector shown in the image below on to a PCB? I was unable to find an Eagle library for the same. If it is not possible to solder on to a PCB, any ideas on how I could interface b/w a PCB and such a connector?

[image: panel mounted DC connector]

Thanks.

Comment: Is there some reason you couldn't choose a more suitable connector?

Comment: I would if I had a choice, but the customer we are designing for has already chosen an enclosure with a round hole for the DC connector. And prefers to use this type of connector. I had never used this connector before so was wondering how to solder it on to a PCB!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is, but I see a problem with that- you'd have to pass it through the panel first, so serviceability of the PCB would be severely constrained. The PCB could use round holes, but slots would be better, and you'd have to take some care if there were traces and pads on the connector side to design the footprint and apply keep-outs to avoid potential shorts- or space the connector off the board a bit. That kind of rigid mechanical/electrical connection is a potential failure point, so that should be considered (for example, dropping the device will put stress on the connections because the PCB has inertia).

At risk of stating the obvious, the usual way of 'interfacing' is to attach wires to the jack and then affix them to the board, either directly or through a connector. If you want to do a nice job, shrink wrap on each wire can be used.

[image: http://www.trossenrobotics.com/resize/shared/images/pimages/cbl-psquid-b.jpg?bw=1000&bh=1000]

If you use a connector small enough to pass through the mounting hole (Edit: and the inside of the nut, perhaps sideways), then the entire thing can be disassembled without unsoldering or cutting. In a production product, that would have the additional advantage that the harness subassemblies could be manufactured or procured with wires and connector attached, and simply snapped together in final assembly.

Comment: Agreed - I would prefer not to use this type of connector on a PCB. However, I am not sure I understand how this connector would fit on to a PCB (even with slots). Aren't the connector 'legs' aligned on different planes? Would I need to bend the legs in order to make them 'sit' on to a PCB? Thanks.

Comment: The board would **have** to be parallel to the panel, and would have three slots in it, one for each leg of the jack. Sometimes designers use small transition boards that are connectorized, but I see little advantage in that here.

Comment: I see, OK - that would make sense. By "connector small enough to pass through the mounting hole..", are you saying basically some cable that passes through the mounting hole and then connects to the DC connector outside of the enclosure? Thanks.

Comment: If you bring the connector (say a female 2mm pitch connector) up to the hole (from the outside of the enclosure), feed it and the wires through, feed the nut over the connector and along the wires, insert the jack in the panel, then thread the nut on and tighten you have the jack attached to the panel, a female connector that can go onto a male header located just about anywhere you like on the PCB, and few constraints as to PCB orientation or mounting.

Answer (score 5):

Break out some calipers or a ruler and make your own eagle footprint.

Or you know, interface it with wires like it's designed for. Board mounting a panel mounted part is non standard use.

[image]

Comment: OK thanks. I had not used this connector before so did not know that it's supposed to be interfaced with wires. Could not find any reference images on the web, showing this type of wire connection.

Comment: @nk2020 see edit for picture of similar jack with wires soldered on.

Answer (score 3):

A connector like this:
[image] [digikey](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/PJ-066A/CP-066A-ND/2627225)
is intended for PCB soldering and is also panel-mounted.
(Whether or not this is a good idea is debatable...)